# Windows search function failed to find my file

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

I have a file named "Form_MS" on my hard disk somewhere in drive D. When I search for it, windows fails to find it. I even copy-pasted its name in case I'm typing it wrongly. Which files and folders is it able to find and why it fails to find my document (MS Word)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the drive `D:\` is indexed.

Search control panel for indexing options and index `D:\` this might take more space but it should solve the issue. This also will take some time, depending on the number of files on `D:\`

By default not many places are indexed

[image: Screen Shot of Indexing Options]

Click Modify and then add D:\

Or you can try for a third party search program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done what you mentioned above, but again "0" files matches my search.

Comment: Indexing takes a moment, give it some time before trying again.

Comment: @Gigili Also don't forget about the third party search apps out there, some are pretty good, but I haven't had one since Windows XP, also I might suggest Using windows Explorer in Desktop mode and search there.

Answer (score 0):

> When I search for it, windows fails to find it.

Tap the Desktop tile to switch to the desktop and use Explorer. After Explorer opens, navigate to `D:`. Then click in the search bar. You can get your results immediately.

[image]